# What are some architectural best practices to consider when designing a point-based permissions system like Stack Overflow uses?

Tags: architecture, permissions, points

Stack Overflow has a points-based permissions system that determines a lot of things on the site, such as what you can edit and the ability to add new tags to the system.

What advice, specifically with regards to architectural implementation, would you give to someone designing such a system? Where do you store permissions? How do you use these permissions to determine what fields appear editable in the view? Are there any good open-source code examples to study from?

With regards to ownership or sharing of a object model such as a question or document, what are the pros/cons of storing a reference to the owner on that object's model versus storing a reference to that object in the account model? e.g.

```
document = { id:          21234,
             owner_id:    4d3ca9f1c067,
             shared_with: [a50d1e000138, 4d3ca9f1c067a, 50d1e000138] }
```

vs.

```
user = { id:              4d3ca9f1c067,
         documents_owned: [21234, 31452, 12312],
         collaborates_on: [23432, 43642, 12314, 23453] }
```

Comment: I also asked this on Quora: http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-architectural-best-practices-to-consider-when-designing-a-point-based-permissions-system-like-StackOverflow-uses

Answer (score 1):

Store the permission in a separate model as permission-required points pairs.

In the view, determine whether the logged-in user has sufficient permissions per item to display, referring to the permissions model described above.

Model options: I'd prefer the former since (1) it has a simpler, flatter structure, so no nested loops through the user table when listing questions, and (2) deleting a document will not entail updating a user object. (Unless their score drops when the doc is deleted or such.)

Comment: If you are using Javascript, you can use underscore.js to simplify the nested loops issue you mentioned. Here's an example function for the account model: ownsOrCollaborates: function (model) { return _.include(model.get("owners"), this.id) || _.include(model.get("collaborators"), this.id) }

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not familiar with `underscore.js`. I am familiar with functional programming, so I know a nested loop can be easy to express, but a single loop is still conceptually simpler :)

Comment: I agree. If you work with JS at all. It's worth checking out underscore.js